# To find formal products in given expressions

Tags: combinatorics

For each of the following expressions, list the list of all formal products in which exponents sum to 4.

(a)$(1+x+x^{2})^{2} (1+x)^{2}$

(b) $(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4})^{3}$

(c)$(1+x^{2}+x^{4})^{2} (1+x+x^{2})^{2}$

(d)$(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+...)$

The answers are
. (a) 7 products—$xxxx$,$x^{3}11x$, $x^{3}1x1$,$x^{3}x11$, $1x ^{3}1x$, $1x^{ 3}x1$, $xx^ {3}11$,

(b) 5 products—$1x ^{4}$, $xx^{ 3}$, $x^{ 2}x^{ 2}$, $x ^{3}x$, $x ^{4}$,

(c) 7 products

(d) 15 products—$x ^{4}11$,$ x^{ 3}x1$, $x^{ 3}1x$, $x ^{2}x^{ 2}1$, $x ^{2}xx$, $x ^{2}1x^{ 2}$,$ xx ^{3}1$, $xx ^{2}x$, $xxx ^{2}$,$x^{1}x ^{3}$, $1x^{ 4}1$, $1x ^{3}x$, $1x ^{2}x^{ 2}$,$ 1xx ^{3}$, $11x^{ 4}$

But I need the method to find formal products as I just know if $i$th polynomial factor contains $r_{i}$ different terms and there are n factors then there will be $r_1×r_2×...r_n$ formal products. 
Please help

Comment: Are these supposed to be the actual answers or your attempted answers? Because they seem strange to me. It seems like by "formal product" it means all the different products you get by expanding the expression and $\textit{not}$ simplifying any of the resulting terms. So where are the $x^3$ factors coming from in the answer to (a)? Also, what about the formal product $x^2\cdot x^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ for (a)?

Comment: These are actual answers and I am not getting the things as you asked about formal product ($x^{2}.x^{2}.1.1$)

Comment: Then I'm not really sure what to make of the question. Firstly, it seems like the term "formal product" in this question is not being used in the same way the term is usually used. My best guess as to what the author means is to take all possible products without simplifying and then find the ones with exponents that sum to $4$. i.e. the formal products of $(1 + x)^2$ are $1\cdot1$, $1\cdot x$, $x\cdot1$, and $x\cdot x$. But this approach doesn't match up with the supposed answers, and frankly some of the "answers" seem nonsensical to me. (But it's always possible that I'm missing something).

Comment: Yes, the author means is to take all possible products without simplifying and then find the ones with exponents that sum to 4. You are right . But it's irony that you are finding these answers non sensible

Comment: The formal products of $(1+x)^{2}$are 1⋅1,1⋅x,x⋅1, and x⋅x as you said. Similarly I need formal products of expressions I asked

Comment: Well, as I said, interpreting the problem this way I cannot see how to get those answers. If you'd like I can outline in an answer how I would do (a) so that you can work out the rest, but it is quite different from the answer you are "supposed" to get.

Comment: It would be great if you post the method for atleast (a) without referring the answers i mentioned. I'll work out others . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a "formal product" is an unsimplified term in the expanded product, then here is how one should reason about (a).

The expression in (a) is $(1 + x + x^2)(1 + x + x^2)(1 + x)(1 + x)$. A formal product is formed by picking a single term from each factor and then multiplying these terms together. For example $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ is the formal product formed by choosing $1$ from each factor. We would like to write down all of the formal products with exponents summing to $4$. There are $3$ choices for the first factor. Namely, $1$, $x$, or $x^2$.

1. If we choose $1$ from the first factor then we $\textit{must}$ choose $x^2$ from the second factor and $x$ from the third and fourth factors. All other choices result in an exponent sum less than $4$. Thus, one of the formal products we seek is $1\cdot x^2\cdot x \cdot x$.
2. If we choose $x$ from the first factor then we must either choose $x$ or $x^2$ from the second, otherwise we can't get a high enough exponent. Choosing $x$ from the second means we also need $x$ from the third and fourth. Choosing $x^2$ from the second means we need $1$ from the third and $x$ from the fourth, or vice versa. This gives us three more formal products: $x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot x$ and $x \cdot x^2 \cdot 1 \cdot x$ and $x \cdot x^2 \cdot x \cdot 1$.
3. If we choose $x^2$ from the first factor then we are free to choose anything from the second. Choosing $1$ means that we need $x$ from the third and fourth. Choosing $x$ means we need $1$ from the third and $x$ from the fourth, or vice versa. Finally, choosing $x^2$ means we need $1$ from the third and fourth. This gives us four more formal products: $x^2\cdot 1 \cdot x \cdot x$ and $x^2 \cdot x \cdot 1 \cdot x$ and $x^2 \cdot x \cdot x \cdot 1$ and $x^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$.

So, there are $8$ formal products with exponents summing to $4$ in (a). The others can be done in a similar fashion.